# Why is Jackson messing with the parsing of application/javascript?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

so I have this RESTful Spring Boot API that reads a JS file from the file system and exposes the contents of this file. Currently, this is how I return the contents of that JS file to the API consumer:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok().header("Content-Type", "application/javascript").body(jsText) // jsText is a String variable
```

This is (partially) what API consumer sees:

```
(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
    w[l] = w[l] || [];
    w[l].push({});
 ....)
```

Now I'm working on a totally unrelated feature that required me to introduce a config class to configure Jackson serialization of `java.time` classes:

```
@Configuration
class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private final static String DATE_TIME_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper

    @Override
    void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_PATTERN, Locale.default)

        objectMapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat)
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())

        jacksonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper)
        converters.add(jacksonConverter)

        super.configureMessageConverters(converters)
    }
}
```

And this is where my problems start. As soon as I added the `converters.add(jacksonConverter)` line, the response from that same endpoint changed to this:

```
"(function (w, d, s, l, i) {\n  w[l] = w[l] || [];\n  w[l].push({});\n..."
```

(notice the `"` and `\n` characters in there)

Now, what am I doing wrong here? If I look at the response headers, it still says `application/javascript` after the change, but why have the contents changed?

Can I avoid / work around this somehow? I mean, I still need the part about `JavaTimeModule`, but would like to avoid breaking the API consumers (they can't parse the version with `"` and `\n`...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> is is how I return the contents of that JS file to the API consumer

since you have your javascript in file and not dynamic Why dont you go to the standard for spring to expose the resources?

In your WebConfiguration (the class that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter) override addResourceHandlers method

```
@Override 
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)   {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/javascript/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/"); 
}
```

All you need then is to put your file under src/main/resources/static and request your file, lets say your file name is script.js and you are running your server on localhsot:8080, the request will be

```
http://localhost:8080/javascript/script.js
```

Comment: That's actually a very good idea! Thanks for the insight, I love it!

Comment: if that solves your issue feel free to \accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it via configuration items on `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  jackson:
    date-format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
    serialization:
      write_dates_as_timestamps: false
```

With these configs in place, I removed the `WebConfig` class and everything works fine: I have both the JS rendering and the `java.time` formatting working as expected.